# create-android-project.sh:line 103:/home/laschweinski/android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/android:No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I want to set development environment of Cocos2d-x for Android in eclipse using Windows. I am getting this error when execute create-android-project.sh

1. Android sdk path is D:\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk\tools
2. NDK path is D:\AndroidGameTool\Android-ndk

Answer (score 0):

Open `create-android-project.sh` file, you should see two line codes like this:

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/laschweinski/android/android-ndk-r5"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="/home/laschweinski/android/android-sdk-linux_86"
```

Then what you just need replace these paths with yourself's paths, as mentioned in your post

```
NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="D:\AndroidGameTool\Android-ndk"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="D:\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk"
```

Comment: I have changed create-android-project.sh as     NDK_ROOT_LOCAL="D:\AndroidGameTool\android-ndk"
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT_LOCAL="D:\Software\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk" but it shows me    D:\AndroidGameTool\Cocos2d-x\create-android-project.sh: line 106: D:\Software\ad
t-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk/tools/android: No such file or directory

Comment: @Mursaleen since you are in window, you can try to use `create-android-project.bat`.

Comment: now i have executed .bat file and it created a project, but when i execute build_native.sh using Cygwin it shows me "bash: build_native.sh: command not found"

Comment: try `./build_native.sh` or `bash build_native.sh`